# Asp.net MVC - LINQ and Hieararchical data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a database with this two tables

```
ProductCategory    
 IDCat
 Name
 Description


ProductSubCategories
 IDSub
 Name
 IDCat
```

This tables are related trought IDCat.

How can i do with LINQ to retrieve the list of Category and SubCategory grouped by Category ??

In my PartialView I would like create a menu with Category and SubCategories like this :

```
Category1
    SubCategory1
    SubCategory2
    SubCategory3
 Category2
    SubCategory1
    SubCategory2
    SubCategory3
 Category3
    SubCategory1
```

Comment: What LINQ provider are you using? LINQ to SQL? LINQ to Entities?

Answer (score 0):

```
MyDataContext db=new MyDataContext();

IQueryable<ProductCategory> categories= db.Categories;

foreach (Category c in categories){
  Console.WriteLine (c.Name);
  foreach (ProductSubCategories sub in c.ProductSubCategories){
    Console.Writeline (sub.Name);
  }  
}
```

**Edit to put answer in View Format**

```
<% foreach (Category c in Model){ %>
<%= Html.Encode(c.Name) %> <br />
    <% foreach (ProductSubCategories sub in Model.Categories){ %>        
        <%= Html.Encode(sub.Name) %> <br />               
    <% } %>
<%} %>
```

This should work (or be close), but I have note tested syntax.  Note that as others have indicated, your primary and foriegn keys must be set up correctly for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your PK-FK correctly in DB, LINQ to SQL will do the object association for you. So there will be a property in ProductCategory as an EntitySet of ProductSubCategory.

The key is that you DB PK-FK ref must be correct for the LINQ code generator to pick this up.